# PayPal on Mobile

Tags: mobile, paypal

I am using Applicationcraft.com (AC) for a mobile native app. This will run on iOS and Android. I need to post transaction details to PayPal and get an authorization back.

AC is based on jQuery and built with Phonegap. Has anyone got a simplified example on how to achieve this? I have looked at the PayPal docs and they are overwhelming for a newcomer.

AC allows http requests so I feel this would be the simplest route.

Comment: I am searching the PayPal Express 
Checkout Integration 
Guide docs to try and get a simple example going. The Docs states : The return URL is the page to which PayPal redirects your buyer’s browser after the buyer 
logs into PayPal and approves the payment. How do I know the URL if my app is native ?

Comment: I am using the following in an app: window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?method=post&cmd=_xclick&business=XXXXX@googlemail.com&lc=UK&item_name=TestItem&amount=1&currencycode=GBP"); This opens a childbrowser on the device (so the user does not jump out to a web browser). The only issue is the child browser does not auto close. Is there anything I can add to the above to force the child window to close on successful completion. I can then process the order as the payment has been made.